# variable in template derive class not recognize. c++

Tags: c++

it seem , i have a problem to get from template derive class into variables which found on base class.

the error i get is :

```
Error   C2065   'a': undeclared identifier  
Error   C2065   'b': undeclared identifier
```

here the code:

--->>base.h

```
#ifndef _BASE_H
#define _BASE_H

template <class T>
class base
{
    T a, b;
public:
    T getMull1();
    base(T q,T W);
    ~base();
};

#include "base.cpp"

#endif
```

-->> base.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "base.h"

#ifndef BASE_IMPL__
#define BASE_IMPL__


template<class T>
T base<T>::getMull1()
{
    return a * b;
}

template<class T>
base<T>::base(T q, T W)
{
    this->a = q;
    this->b = W;
}

template <class T>
base<T>::~base()
{
}

#endif
```

-->>derive1.h

```
#ifndef _DERIVE1_H
#define _DERIVE1_H

#include "base.h"
template <class T>
class derive1 :
    public base<T>
{
public:
    T getMull();
    derive1(T q, T W);
    ~derive1();
};

#include "derive1.cpp"
#endif
```

-->>derive1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "derive1.h"


#ifndef DERIVE1_IMPL__
#define DERIVE1_IMPL__

template<class T>
T derive1<T>::getMull() 
{
    return a*b;
}

template<class T>
derive1<T>::derive1(T q, T W):base<T>(q,W)
{
}

template<class T>
derive1<T>::~derive1()
{
}


#endif
```

-->>main

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "derive1.h"

derive1<int> myDerive(1,4);
int main()
{
    int ans = myDerive.getMull1(); //working fine on the base
        ans = myDerive.getMull();   // not working 
    return 0;
}
```

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You should see [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: dependent name, you have to use `return this->a * this->b;` or `return base<T>::a * base<T>::b;`.

Comment: thanks u , its working.